# Synchronization of postgres and mysql database server?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, synchronization

What's the best way to synchronize few tables of mysql server with postgreSQL server?
Currently people are executing scripts, which takes much time, is there any fast solution available from which we can map the tables and columns to synchronize the db server.

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the data from one and consume it with the other.  Something like a web service, linked server, open data framework, ODBC driver, etc.  Postgres has a nice ODBC driver that works pretty well.

Comment: CSV export/import in easy way with a couple of shell scripts.